# Simple question about changing bases in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let V be a vector space of dimension n. Consider bases $v_1, v_2 ... v_n$ and $w_1, w_2, ... w_n$. Is there a
linear map $f : V \rightarrow V$ such that $f(v_i) = cw_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$ and some scalar c?
What about $f(v_i) = w_i$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In fact, for any choice of scalars ${c_i}_{i=1}^n$, there is a unique linear map $f$ which satisfies this. Particularly, for $c_i=1$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a particular way to construct this map, or at least show its existence?

Comment: A linear map is determined uniquely by how it acts on the basis elements. Meaning - once you choose what $f$ does to your basis (like you did), $f$ is determined uniquely. This is due to the fact that $f$ is linear, and any vector in your space can be written as a linear combination of basis elements.